# eclipse debug mode skip external jars

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I am trying to debug my project in Eclipse.However when I run it in debug mode and use the step over option the control is going into the jdk and spring classes as well.I do not want to include these external jar source code in my debug mode.
Please help how I can achieve that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Debug->Step Filtering

Check the box "Use Step Filters" and then add more filters if needed, and enable the filters you want to use.

For more information: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm?cp=1_4_7_2_20